# ERROR: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.9'

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qmake

My OS X 10.10 build machine just updated to X Code 7 via the app store. Now I am getting the error that the 10.9 SDK was not found.

qmake pro file

```
macx {
    QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9
}
```

How can I build software for OS X 10.9 Mavericks users?

Comment: Xcode 7 only includes 10.11 SDK.

Comment: @baf, yes I know. But what does that mean for my deployment process?

Comment: I am also confused. My quick fix was to copy SDK from `Xcode 6`. I am interested to hear other developers' opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build against the latest SDK but still target older OS X versions by setting the deployment target (which you have set). If you remove the QMAKE_MAC_SDK line, it should do what you want.

Comment: Great thanks! Additional note: For Qt Creator to work I had to manually add `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.11` to `<Qt Installation path>/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf`. It was somehow defaulting to 10.10 but I don't know where it got that from. Maybe from Installation time.